# Cannot delete print job on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing

If I print something and the printer is not available, the print job is queued and the queue can be shown, using the global configuration menue (Devices -> Printers). There for each printer device the number of pending jobs is shown as button. Selecting this button opens a dialog window with a list of pending jobs. Every job in one line is combined with buttons. One of this buttons is a cancel button. But selecting this cancel-button does not do anything.

How can I delete pending print jobs?
Is there any workaround with a shell command?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **lprm** command:

Use

```
man lprm
```

to get a description.

To delete all queued jobs:

```
lprm -
```

---

**NAME**
lprm - cancel print jobs

**SYNOPSIS**

```
   lprm [ -E ] [ -U username ] [ -h server[:port] ] [ -P destination[/instance] ]
   [ - ] [ job-id(s) ]
```

**DESCRIPTION**

> lprm cancels print jobs that have been queued for printing.  If  no  arguments
> are supplied, the current job on the default destination is canceled.  You can
> specify one or more job ID numbers to cancel those jobs or use the - option to
> cancel all jobs.

**OPTIONS**

```
   The lprm command supports the following options:

   -E   Forces encryption when connecting to the server.

   -P destination[/instance]
        Specifies the destination printer or class.

   -U username
        Specifies an alternate username.

   -h server[:port]
        Specifies an alternate server.

   The  CUPS  version of lprm is compatible with the standard Berkeley command of the same name.
```

**EXAMPLES**

- Cancel the current job on the default printer:

  ```
    lprm
  ```
- Cancel job 1234:

  ```
    lprm 1234
  ```
- Cancel all jobs:

  ```
    lprm -
  ```